# Spring boot cloud kubernetes - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Restart endpoint is not enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot microservice with kubernetes dependencies for configmap and secret support.The current spring boot version is 2.3.9.RELEASE . and the kubernetes dependency version is 1.1.0.RELEASE . its an old one , so i tried to update the dependency to its latest 1.1.10.RELEASE.
This is the updated pom details

```
<spring-cloud-kubernetes.version>1.1.10.RELEASE</spring-cloud-kubernetes.version>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-kubernetes.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>       
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-kubernetes-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud-kubernetes.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

After updating the kubernetes dependency version to 1.1.10.RELEASE , am getting the below error while stating the app

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyChangeWatcher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/config/reload/ConfigReloadAutoConfiguration$ConfigReloadAutoConfigurationBeans.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'propertyChangeWatcher' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationUpdateStrategy' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/config/reload/ConfigReloadAutoConfiguration$ConfigReloadAutoConfigurationBeans.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.config.reload.ConfigurationUpdateStrategy]: Factory method 'configurationUpdateStrategy' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Restart endpoint is not enabled
```

This is my bootstrap.yml file

```
    spring:
      cloud:
        kubernetes:
          reload:
           enabled: true
           monitoring-config-maps: true
           mode: polling
           period: 15000
           strategy: restart_context
          config:
            enabled: true
            sources:
               - name: demo
          secrets:      
            enabled: true        
            enable-api: true
            sources:
               - name: demo-secret
    
    management:
      endpoint:
        restart:
          enabled: true
        health:
          enabled: true
        info:
          enabled: true
        env:
          enabled: true
        refresh:
          enabled: true
```

This is my application.yml file

```
management:
    endpoints:
        beans:
            enabled: false
        web:
            exposure:
                include: prometheus,info,refresh,health,env,restart
        prometheus:
            path: /api/actuator/prometheus
            sensitive: false
```

I have enabled the restart endpoint , but still its not working . Please help me on this .
I tried the below way also , but still throwing the same issue.

```
 <properties>
        <spring.cloud-version>Hoxton.SR12</spring.cloud-version>
   </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with spring [spring-cloud-aws-starter](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-aws)
I stumbled across this [github issue.](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/540)

It relies on the the actuator being enabled.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Plus this configuration in your application.yml:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    restart:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info,restart
```